Defiition of discrete/continous random variables and motivation of them.
I'm a first year math degree student and I'm taking a probability course. We defined what a random variable is and when it is discrete/continuous, but the professor didn't explain in a rigorous way what they really are. Wikipedia says that a discrete variable is one whose image is numerable, and it is cotinuous if it's not. This is similar to what, my professor told us. But when we advanced a bit in the subject, this becomes a bit weird in some cases, specially because of the definitions of mass and density functions.
For example, let's consider the probabilistic space $(\Bbb R, \mathcal B, P)$, where $P: \mathcal B \to [0,1]$ is the probability function such that $P(S)=1$  if  $0 \in S$ and $P(S)=0$ in other case, where $S \in \mathcal B$.  Now let's consider $X$ be the identity random variable in $\Bbb R$. Is this a continuous random variable? Clearly the image of $X$ is not numerable, but it behaves like what we'd call a discrete radom variable, and my professor would call it a discrete random variable. I asked wether the definition could be that $X$ is discrete when the set $\{ X(\omega) \in \Bbb R : P(\omega) \neq 0 \}$ is numerable. But this does't make much sense because precisely when we have a continuous random varialbe, the probability of any single point is $0$.
And my question becomes relevant because we defined the mass and density function like this:
If $X$ is a discrete random variable then its mass function is $f: \Bbb R \to [0,1]$ defined as:
$$f(a)=P(X^{-1}(a))$$
And if $X$ is continuous, its density function is another function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that:
$$P(X^{-1}((-\infty, x)) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt  \forall  x \in \Bbb R$$
We didn't prove that every continuous random variable can have a density function, but we had to trust our professor, I guess. And in the continuous case, we define the distribution function as $F: \Bbb R \to [0,1]$ s.t. $F(x)=P(X^{-1}((-\infty, x))$.
Can there be a probabilistic space $(\Bbb R, \mathcal B, P)$ such that the density function of the identity random variable doesn't exist? I think that an example would be one in which the distribution function would be $F:\Bbb R \to [0,1]$ s.t.:
$$ F(x) = 0, x \le 0 $$
$$ F(x) = \frac{x}{2} x, 0 \lt x \le 1 $$
$$ F(x) = \frac{1}{2}, 1 \lt x \lt 2 $$
$$ F(x) = 1, 2 \le x $$
I won't try to put the probability function that it'd have associated explicitly, but I think that such a probability space can exist. In that case, X would be in the middle of discrete and continuous; using the definition, it's continuous, but it can't have a density function because the distribution function is not continuous. Maybe this has something to do with what wikipedia calls "absolute continuous" random varuiables, because it says that only those can have a density function. This seems strange to me because of what my professor has told me, but at this point I do't know (also, in the section of examples, wikipedia defines continous as having a continuous distribution function, which contradicts the previous definition, right?).
That said, I have another question about random variables which is not mathematical but about the motivation. Basically, why do we use random variables? In my examples, I use identity random variables, which looks just like having to do an extra step for no reason. And the main reason we had been sutudying this is because the next chapter in the chapter was about statistical models. Can't we just study those only using our probabilistic space, without having to use a random variable (which is pretty much something like a morphism from our probabilistic space to the canonical $(\Bbb R, \mathcal B, P)$)? The professor said that, for example in the Bermouilli model, if we have $\Omega = $ $\{$success, failure$\}$ then we cannot calculate the expected value. Ok, but... what's the point of calculating the expected value of an experiment which is not numerical? What we do is assign $1$ to success and $0$ to failure, and then, if the probability of succes in the original probabilistic space was p, then the expected value is p. Ok, so in a experiment which consist of obtaining success or failure, the expected value is... p? In an experiment about choosing a random ball from a box with balls of different colours, the expected value is $4,67$? My professor also said that there are more advanced questions in which couldn't be done without random variables.
Thanks for the feedback.

I've read this a few times and still have trouble figuring out exactly what your question is. Can you remove some of the filler to narrow down what you're asking?

Do you know that almost 3 centuries have elapsed between Pascal (the first attested mathematician to have seriously worked on the subject) and the present modelization, elaborated circa 1920-1930 ? Conclusion : it is by no means evident... and many new learners in probability ask themselves the same kind of questions... My advice : a too much theoretical approach is harmful ; instead, take a practical path by working many exercises, do a lot of computer simulations in order to have a concrete "grasp" on the domain, then in a second step only, come back to theory.

@SeanRoberson what are discrete and continuous random variables?

I’m pretty sure Wikipedia did not describe a continuous random variable as one with an image that is not countable. Any CDF with a jump discontinuity but some interval over which it increases continuously would have an uncountable image. So your more sophisticated example is really just an illustration of a random variable with the same CDF as a discrete random variable, but it has an uncountable image. Some people would still call it discrete, nobody would call it continuous. There really is no terminology consensus on your example.

I'm going to use the following facts & terminology about random variables (r.v.s) and cumulative distribution functions (c.d.f.s):

Every r.v. $X$ has a c.d.f. $F:\Bbb R\to [0,1]: x\mapsto P(X\le x),$ which completely characterizes its probability distribution.

A r.v. (and its distribution) is categorized by the "type" of its c.d.f.; in particular, there are four mutually exclusive possibilities: (1) discrete,  (2) absolutely continuous, (3) singular continuous, (4) a mixture of some of the preceding types. This is a consequence of Lebesgue's decomposition theorem:

Every c.d.f. $F$ can be expressed as a weighted sum of three component c.d.f.s:
$$F= p_1 F_{d}+p_2 F_{a.c.}+p_3 F_{s.c.}$$
where $p_1+p_2+p_3=1$,  with $p_i\ge0$, and $F_d,F_{a.c.},F_{s.c.}$ are c.d.f.s of the following types:

Discrete:  $F_d$ is a step-function with countably many points of discontinuity.
Absolutely continuous: $F_{a.c.}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^xF_{a.c.}^\prime(t) dt$ for all $x$.
Singular continuous: $F_{s.c.}$ is continuous, with $F_{s.c.}^\prime=0$  almost everywhere.


Every c.d.f. $F$ has only countably many points of discontinuity, and its derivative $F^\prime$ exists almost everywhere (i.e. any exceptions form a set of measure zero).

A distribution is called continuous iff the c.d.f. is everywhere continuous (i.e., there is no discrete component), which is the case iff $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$.



Wikipedia says that a discrete variable is one whose image is numerable, and it is cotinuous if it’s not.

Your example of an identity function proves otherwise: a r.v. can have all of $\Bbb R$ as its image, yet have a discrete distribution (that is, a distribution concentrated on a countable set, which is equivalent to the c.d.f. being a step function). Also, because a mixture is one of the possibilities, it's not true that a distribution must be either discrete or continuous. It is true that if there is no discrete component, then it must be continuous, and if no continuous component then it must be discrete.

For example, let's consider the probabilistic space $(\Bbb R, \mathcal B, P)$, where $P: \mathcal B \to [0,1]$ is the probability function such that $P(S)=1$  if  $0 \in S$ and $P(S)=0$ in other case, where $S \in \mathcal B$.  Now let's consider $X$ be the identity random variable in $\Bbb R$. Is this a continuous random variable?

Unfortunately the terminology does leave something to be desired. This r.v. $X$ is said to be of discrete type (referring to its distribution),  although of course the function $X$ is continuous, being the  identity function on $\Bbb R$. Now, $P(X=0) = 1$, which makes the c.d.f. a step function with just one jump (at $x=0$). Thus, the distribution is discrete and is completely concentrated on one point (what's called "degenerate").

if $X$ is continuous, its density function is another function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that:
$$P(X^{-1}((-\infty, x)) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt  \forall  x \in \Bbb R$$
We didn't prove that every continuous random variable can have a density function, but we had to trust our professor, I guess.

What you're calling a "continuous" r.v. actually refers to a r.v. whose c.d.f. is absolutely continuous, as it's for such case that the derivative of the c.d.f. plays the role of $f$ in the above equation. (One can say that c.d.f. $F$ is absolutely continuous iff there is a function $f$ satisfying the above equation for all $x$, or one can say iff $F^\prime$ exists almost everywhere and is Lebesgue integrable -- the two definitions can be proved equivalent.)

in the continuous case, we define the distribution function as $F: \Bbb R \to [0,1]$ s.t. $F(x)=P(X^{-1}((-\infty, x))$.

Ordinarily, the c.d.f. is in all cases defined as $F: \Bbb R\to[0,1]:x\mapsto P\left(X^{-1}((-\infty, x])\right).$ It's just that in the continuous case the result is the same either way.

Can there be a probabilistic space $(\Bbb R, \mathcal B, P)$ such that the density function of the identity random variable doesn't exist?

Yes, as shown by the piecewise-defined c.d.f. $F$ that you give, which is a mixture of discrete and absolutely continuous c.d.f.s; i.e., $F=pF_d+(1-p)F_{a.c.}.$
